# Auto login to wifi networks

Tags: wi-fi

My university redirects me to a https login page when accessing internet through wifi. This is irritating when trying to connect to the Internet from my Android phone. I was wondering whether there is some application to do logging in whenever that application is opened (storing credentials, of course)? If not, how can I create such an application? Is there any previous application created (with open source code) that is customized for automating logging into certain networks?

Comment: Development questions are offtopic here.  There are apps to do this, though I'm not sure if they're open source.

Comment: For the record: https://market.android.com/details?id=org.wifibrowserlogin and 
https://market.android.com/details?id=co.uk.syslynx.wifiweblogin

Comment: The new URl https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.uk.syslynx.wifiwebloginapp

Answer (score 1):

I use "[Hotspot Droid Lite"](http://www.appbrain.com/app/hotspot-droid-lite/org.dyndns.nagaw.hotspot.lite) for this (although I don't use the html login option)

We evaluated several in our workplace and this is one of the simplest to use.

There will be others on the market (as per Lie Ryan's comment)